# Obtener elementos del DOM de manera dinámica en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy armando un framework propio para ajustralo a necesidades específicas. Imagino que hay frameworks o librerias que hacen lo que busco, pero la idea es armar una específica. La idea es que a través de fetch obtener un HTML. Esto me devuelve un HTML en texto. Usando DOMParse convierto ese archivo de texto en HTML lo que me posibilita recorrerlo con métodos de Array. La idea es obtener de forma automática todos los elementos que contengan un ID.

Código de fetch y DOMParser

```
    class Utils {
  /**
   * Parsea un documento HTML a través de un texto plano.
   * Es una función asíncrona
   * @param text : texto plano a parsear.
   * @param parserMethod : El método a ser parseado. Por default es "text/html"
   * @class Utiliza la clase DomParser de JS
   * @return HTML Document
   */
  static parseHtml(text = "", parserMethod = "text/html") {
    try {
      if (text !== "") {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const result = parser.parseFromString(text, parserMethod);
        return result;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error al procesar el documento: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Función simple que retorna JSON
   * @param {string}url Url a la que se va a hacer fetch.
   * @param {string}method Método del fetch. GET,POST,DELETE,etc.
   * @param {string}responseMethod El método con el que parsear la información en la primer instancia de fetch. Por default es un json.
   * @return Devuelve promesa segun el responseMethod.
   */
  static async fetchToApi(url = "", method = "GET", responseMethod = "json") {
    try {
      if (url !== "") {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
        });
        switch (responseMethod) {
          case "blob":
            return response.blob();
          case "text":
            return response.text();
          default:
            return response.json();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(` ${error}`);
    }
  }
```

Luego la función que obtiene todos los elementos por ID es esta:

```
class DomElements {
  constructor() {
    this.Nodes = {};
    this.open();
  }

  async open() {
    try {
      const textHtml = await Utils.fetchToApi(
        "http://localhost/mailchimp/index.php",
        "GET",
        "text"
      );

      const result = Utils.parseHtml(textHtml).documentElement.querySelectorAll("*");
      console.log(result);
      result.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.id !== "") {
          if (!this.Nodes.hasOwnProperty(element.id)) {
          
            this.Nodes[element.id] = document.getElementById(element.id);
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Todo esto funciona pero el resultado que me da es un objeto en el cual no tiene propiedades y los elementos del DOM quedan "por fuera" del objeto en si. Este es el resultado en consola después de instanciar mi clase DOMElements

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cómo estás instanciado tu clase? Tienes llamadas asíncronas en el constructor, por lo cual es posible que al momento de hacer `console.log` del objeto recién instanciado, el mismo aún no ha terminado de recibir el resultado de las llamadas asíncronas. Falta algo más de información para poder determinar el problema. Saludos